# MediaWiki: How to resolve "descriptionmsg" value retrieved via API?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api

Via http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&meta=siteinfo&formatversion=2&format=json&siprop=extensions you can retrieve information about the MediaWiki extensions installed. The result format is documented at https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Siteinfo and states that for each extension `descriptionmsg` contains a system message name. This is not the description itself but a key to a description string.

My question is: I have the key from `descriptionmsg`, now how do I obtain the description string (via the API)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MediaWiki has an API module in its action API called allmessages, it can be called like https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&meta=allmessages&ammessages=centralauth-desc

Check out its documentation here: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Allmessages

Comment: Interesting! Thank you, I'll definitively have a look at that in a view hours!

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the contents of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki:[descriptionmsg_value]

Replace `[descriptionmsg_value]` with the actual value. For example given `"descriptionmsg":"timedmediahandler-desc"` the related page is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki:timedmediahandler-desc.

There are several ways to get the contents of a page. Refer to [API:Get the contents of a page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Get_the_contents_of_a_page) for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much for this information. At first glance your approach seems to work, but at second glance there are problems. If I open an URL with "MediaWiki:....." I indeed get a valid response. But I need the raw data. Therefore I tried to add "action=raw" which strangely and silently failed on my MW installation without any error message. If I try to retrieve the content via API I get "known=true" but "missing=true" as well (and no content). (And the title has been normalized from lower case to upper case.) So any idea how to get the data without parsing the skin specific HTML output?